# Email Not Sending In Loop Condition

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I have a Designer 2013 WF logic displayed below:

[image]

The purpose is to send an email every time the condition is met.

***The Requirement:***

To send a daily email reminder after Submitted Date + 14 days condition has been met. But for testing purposes I'm using 1 minute intervals.

It would have been very ideal to use a "Start a Task Process" and just set a Due Date but when I use it, the logic in "Transition to stage" never fires.

What I mean is, even when CurrentItem:RequestStatus equals ReadyforCPFImplementation, it ***NEVER*** goes to Assign New Designee stage. The same thing applies for the other logic.

Hence, the reason I'm using a Loop and another reason why I am using the "Wait for Event:When an item is changed" logic.

If I can use Start a Task Process can someone tell me how to arrange logic in "Transition to stage" to actually work?

If not, how can I make logic in Loop fire?

Comment: Have you tried using the pause action?

Comment: Pause wouldn't be a viable option because I want to send daily emails after Submitted Date + 2 weeks time has passed. I also want the daily emails to keep coming until the Admin completes the review.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this for the email reminder.

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: Hi @MickB. Thanks for the reply. I haven't tested yet due to being pulled for other more pressing duties. Just wanted to know , does this work? I'd appreciate feedback. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the idea is that you have some condition that breaks the loop though. In this instance I used a status column that had two values

Comment: I've tested the loop and it works. I've set the Pause within the loop for 2 minutes for testing purposes. However, when I change the status from Incomplete to something like "Proceed to Next Stage", it takes 2 minutes or more for the logic in the next stage to start. I'm afraid if a user changes the status to something different that it will take a whole day, according to the logic you sent, for the user to even be notified of anything. Why is Loop doing that?

Comment: Yes I see. If you wanted to continue execution of the workflow you could change the original pause length from 14 days to 13 days and move the pause for 24 hours action to just before the if statement. You would still get the 13day + 24hrs = 14-day initial wait period and the loop wouldn't cause the extra 24hr pause period. Note that it would still would not be immediate if the list item changed, but within a single 24hr period. See my edit.